# Exception thrown when running test on Mule config file

Tags: spring, mule

The exception following exception is thrown when running tests on the config file included. Any ideas what the cause might be?

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'muleTxMgr' defined in URL [src/test/resources/com/thrivent/em/db/config/xa-transaction-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mule.util.NetworkUtils.getLocalHost()Ljava/net/InetAddress;
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'muleTxMgr' defined in URL [/src/test/resources/com/sma/edb/config/xa-transaction-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mule.util.NetworkUtils.getLocalHost()Ljava/net/InetAddress;
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mule.util.NetworkUtils.getLocalHost()Ljava/net/InetAddress;

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd

> Blockquote

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/bti http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/bti/current/mule-bti-ee.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd  
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd  
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
 <context:property-placeholder location="com/sma/edb/config/hsql.database.properties"></context:property-placeholder>
 <jbossts:transaction-manager></jbossts:transaction-manager>
 <spring:beans> 
      <spring:bean class="org.mule.config.spring.factories.MuleTransactionManagerFactoryBean" id="muleTxMgr"></spring:bean> 
      <spring:bean id="hsqlDataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXADataSource"> 
         <spring:property name="driverName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></spring:property>  
         <spring:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></spring:property>  
       <spring:property name="transactionManager" ref="muleTxMgr"></spring:property>  
        <spring:property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"></spring:property>  
         <spring:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></spring:property>  
     </spring:bean>  
     <spring:bean id="dbQuerySql" class="java.lang.String"> 
         <spring:constructor-arg> 
             <spring:value>SELECT 1</spring:value>  
         </spring:constructor-arg>  
     </spring:bean>  
 </spring:beans>
```

-->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a version conflict to me, as `org.mule.util.NetworkUtils.getLocalHost()` has been introduced in version `3.6`.

Comment: Thank you will look into it